# Что означает выражение "select sid from table"?

Tags: sql, plsql

Что означает выражение `select sid  from table`?

Comment: а какое именно слово непонятно? Тут вроде бы и базовых знаний языка достаточно.

Comment: Я думаю ТС интересуется термином [SID](https://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORACLE_SID) - ораклевским `System ID`

Comment: А где вы взяли это выражение? На первый взгляд, оно безсмысленно.

Answer (score 2):

```
select sid  from table
```

`select` -выбрать

`sid` -  название внутренней функций plsql от oracle

`from` - выбрать из

`table` - имя таблицы, из который будем брать `sid`

если по русски то: выбери стоблец с именем `sid` из таблицы `table`

Comment: символична фраза "если по русски", особенно если учесть, что пост изначально был на англ. языке :D

Comment: нет в данном случае sid как раз таки не является колонкой, а название внутренней функций plsql от oracle.

Comment: @AmireevKontakty, учёл, изменил ответ